# animated gif in Python Gtk application

Tags: python, gtk, animated-gif

I wrote an application with Python, Glade and Gtk. 
I like to use an animated GIF inside this application.
So I changed my code, which worked for showing up a PNG. But sadly the animation inside the GIF is not shown, just a static image.

```
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import PixbufAnimation

class Mealscanner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(self.app_path, "template.glade"))

    def upd_signal(self):
        signallight = self.builder.get_object("signal")  # changing signal light
        if (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_CREW_OK or self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_MEAL_OK):
            if (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_CREW_OK):
                pic = Pixbuf.new_from_file(os.path.join(self.app_path, "assets", "scan_next.png"))
            if (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_MEAL_OK):
                pic = Pixbuf.new_from_file(os.path.join(self.app_path, "assets", "green.png"))
                self.log.get_buffer().set_text(self.scanner.display_last_orders())
            signallight.set_from_pixbuf(pic)
        elif (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_ERROR or self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_MEAL_ERROR):
            pic = Pixbuf.new_from_file(os.path.join(self.app_path, "assets", "red.png"))
            signallight.set_from_pixbuf(pic)
        elif (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_IDLE):
            signallight = self.builder.get_object("signal")  # changing signal light
            if (self.scanner.get_status() == self.scanner.STATUS_IDLE):
                inforight.set_text(".-._.-._ Bereit für CREW-Scan _.-._.-.")
                pixbufanim = PixbufAnimation.new_from_file(os.path.join(self.app_path, "assets", "greycode.gif"))
                pixbufanim.get_iter()
                signallight.set_from_animation(pixbufanim)
        retrun True

    # some more methods

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.start_timer()
            GLib.timeout_add(10, self.upd_signal)
            Gtk.main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def quit(self):
        self.scanner.db.close()
        Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Mealscanner()
    app.run()
```

where template.glade defines the object as GtkImage:

```
          <object class="GtkImage" id="signal">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <property name="pixbuf">assets/trans.png</property>
            <style>
              <class name="signal"/>
            </style>
          </object>
```

Any hints on this?

SOLUTION:

The timeout was to short, so the animated gif was re-loaded every 10ms - the animation was slower. After increasing the timeout, the animation was shown.

Comment: See my edit of the question. signallight is GtkImage if Gtk.Builder.get_object() delivers the proper object.

Comment: Works for me, used your shown code with your `template.glade <object ...`. Have you doublechecked your `'grey.gif'` in question is realy a animation?

Comment: Hello @stovl : I doublecheked with another animated gif. Same result. The gif is shown, but without animation. Running on python 3.7 on Debian Bullseye with Gnome 3.34 - maybe there's a problem?

Comment: ***"maybe there's a problem?"***: It's only `Gtk` related, can you confirm, your program get **not stalled** after loading the image. A animated `GIF` needs the `Gtk mainloop` running. Which context, why do you `return True`?

Comment: Ha! The trick is to remove the  "return True" !

Comment: But then, the only the animated gif is shown, and no change can be made (On status-change, I would like to change the image). As result: either animated image or changing image...

Comment: Got it!
Just increase the timeout_add miliseconds, so the animated gif isn't loaded every 10 ms! After that all workes as wished!
Thankx a to stovl for your patience.

Comment: Please post and accept an answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.